# Differentiate between bash/shell & cmd

Tags: php, bash, shell, cmd, command-line-interface

is it possible to make out in what kind of CLI environment I am within a PHP CLI script?

I would like to automatically enable color support for bash instances, both native linux and MingW32/Cygwin bash, and disable it in Windows Command Prompt/Cmd (else it would look ugly).

Comment: I think you're testing for the wrong thing. You don't care about whether the shell is bash, you care about whether the shell supports color commands. Check for that support explicitly with `libtermcap` or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the `$_ENV` array [aka there is an `E` in `variables_order` in your php.ini] then you should be able to read the `SHELL` environment variable.

eg:

```
# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
# php -r 'echo $_ENV["SHELL"];'
/bin/bash
# php -r 'echo ini_get("variables_order");'
EGPCS
```

Comment: hm, yeah, `gentenv()` works well. No output from cmd, `/bin/bash` from cygwin. Thank you.